# Pythonic (and most performant) way to generate the distance between all points while keeping meta_data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains x and y coordinates and an id that looks like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(26, 2)), columns=list('XY'))
df['id'] = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

How do I find the linear distance between one regions and all the other regions in a pythonic way without having a set of nested loops while keeping the O-D region IDs?

The output should yield the same result as:

```
import math
def get_distance(start, end):
    dist = math.hypot(end[0]-start[0], end[1]-start[1])
    return dist

data = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    start = [row['X'], row['Y']]
    start_region = row['id']

    for other_index, other_row in df.iterrows():
        end = [other_row['X'], other_row['Y']]
        end_rengion = other_row['id']
        distance = get_distance(start, end)

        entry = dict(
            start_region = start_region,
            end_rengion = end_rengion,
            distance = distance
        )

        data.append(entry)

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Does `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` or `cdist` help? Keeping the appropriate metadata shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Marginally. I am also looking for a generalized way to solve this kind of problem, my since the next task will be to use the google distance matrix API to calculate travel times between these points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) to do this. It is scipy function, written in c, so is much fast compared to nested python loops.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(26, 2)), columns=list('XY'))
ids = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
df['id'] = ids

# get the points
points = df[["X", "Y"] ].values

# calculate distance of each point from every other point, row i contains contains distances for point i. distances[i, j] contains distance of point i from point j.
distances = distance.cdist(points, points, "euclidean")
distances = distances.flatten()

# get the start and end points
cartesian = list(itertools.product(ids, ids))

data = dict(
            start_region = [x[0] for x in cartesian],
            end_rengion = [x[1] for x in cartesian],
            distance = distances
        )
print(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

Edit according to OP's comment : You can provide custom function to `cdist`, so modifying to replace euclidian distance with the google API point distances shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @Andras Desk Suggested the same thing above. This is has improved the speed up - thanks! 
I am also looking for a generalized way to solve this kind of problem, since the next task will be to use the google distance matrix API to calculate travel times between these points (which will now be coordinates?).
Do you suggest I add a new question specifically with this in mind?

Comment: @JohnyMudly, If I get you correctly, the X, Y would be coordinates of a place and you want to get the distances between every pair of points. This is what we are doing here. If you see the documentation linked in the ans, we can choose any distance metric between the points. So you will just have to replace euclidian with the google matrix distance. Specifically define a wrapper function ``dist(a,b)`` inside which you make call to the google API. Then pass this to cdist instead of euclidean.